# Cannot remove event listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm working on a todo list web app. I have a save button in a form to which I've attached an event listener: `getDom().todoModalSaveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => todoManager.editTodo.bind(caller.id));`
or         `getDom().todoModalSaveBtn.addEventListener('click', todoManager.createTodo.bind(todoManager));`
depending on which element is calling (I'm using the same modal to both edit and save to-dos).
When I was editing my second or third to do in a row, I realised the event listeners keep piling up, so I added this:

```
export function removeSaveBtnEventListeners() {
getDom().todoModalSaveBtn.removeEventListener('click', todoManager.createTodo.bind);
getDom().todoModalSaveBtn.removeEventListener('click', todoManager.editTodo.bind);}
```

which I call from my other module, the one in charge of the todos, but somehow if I look at the HTML & DOM with the inspector, I see that the button has an increasing number of event listeners, so at the time of saving the edits on my third todo, I'm editing two or three at once...

Thanks!

Comment: `.bind(...)` creates a new function ... so, it's not the same function ... anyway ... `x.bind` is a function of it's own, nothing to do with the function returned by `.bind()` - have you read the documentation for `.removeEventListener`?

Comment: Which means? How do I solve it?

Comment: Consider not attaching an anonymous function. Instead name the function, or put it in a variable. Then you can attach or remove it using that name

Comment: Thank you. So I'll have to name the function then. There's still some things in the code but I'll try to figure it out on my own.